# I can't see nfc tag with Error Domain=NFCError Code=203 in obj-c,

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-nfc

None of my NFC reader apps are working.
I'm experiencing this too since the update to iOS 14.
Before Upgrading. it worked well.
**setting** : Xcode Version 12.3, ios 14.3, Mac os Bic sur Version 11.1

code here

```
- (IBAction)startNFCBtn:(id)sender {
    [nfcManager.ndefSession invalidateSession];
    nfcManager.tagReaderSession = [[NFCTagReaderSession alloc] initWithPollingOption:NFCPollingISO14443 delegate:nfcManager queue:nil];
    nfcManager.tagReaderSession.alertMessage = @"Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it.";
    [nfcManager.tagReaderSession beginSession];
}
```

**error here**

> [CoreNFC] 00000002 832b4360 -[NFCHardwareManager queueReaderSession:sessionConfig:completionHandler:]:96  error=Error Domain=NFCError Code=203 "System resource unavailable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=System resource unavailable}
>
> [CoreNFC] 00000002 80080000 -[NFCTagReaderSession beginSessionWithConfig:]:365  error:Error Domain=NFCError Code=203 "System resource unavailable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=System resource unavailable}, errorCode: 0xcb